# POSIX Threads and signal masks

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, posix, mask

Is there a way to change the signal mask of a thread from another thread?
I am supposed to write a multithreaded C application that doesn't use mutex, semaphores and condition variables, only signals.

So it would look like something like this:
The main Thread sends SIGUSR1 to its process and and one of the 2 threads (not including the main thread), will respond to the signal and block SIGUSR1 from the sigmask and sleep. Then the main thread sends SIGUSR1 again, the other thread will respond, block SIGUSR1 from its  sigmask, unblock SIGUSR1 from the other threads sigmask, so it will respond to SIGUSR1 again.

So essentially whenever the main thread sends SIGUSR1 the two other threads swap between each other.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`pthread_sigqueue(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_sigqueue.3.html) called from the main thread, and [`sigwait(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sigwait.3.html) or [`sigtimedwait(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) in the child thread(s).

Comment: pthread_sigqueue would be the perfect choice, but it only works on a linux environment and not on posix generally. It wouldn't compile on Mac os x

Comment: Use `pthread_kill`. `sigqueue` is no better than `kill` except for realtime signals anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A thread can only modify its own signal mask (via `pthread_sigmask()`). If you want to modify another thread's signal mask, you will have to write code yourself to ask the other thread to do it.

Signals are being sent to the process here, so `kill()` or `sigqueue()` are the functions to use. The latter will avoid coalescing multiple signals together which may happen with `kill()`.